# Create user in other controller and view (Rails 4 with Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I try to create users in my admin controller but not to run it always leaves some error.

I use application_helper to log in to my root # home with devise but I do not know if that is what is causing me more problems when creating user

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def resource_name
   :user
  end
  def resource_name_request
   :request
  end

 def resource
   @resource ||= User.new
 end

 def devise_mapping
   @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
 end

end
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb: Aplication Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?



   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     session[:previous_url] ||
     if current_user.role == "admin"
       admin_index_path
     end

   end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :role])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :country])
  end   
end
```

app/models/user.rb: User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

app/controllers/admin_controller.rb: Admin_controller

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index

    @user = User.new
  end


  def create
    request_hash = {
      :name => params[:name],
      :email => params[:email],
      :role => params[:role],
      :password => params[:password],
      :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation]
    }
    @user = User.new(request_hash)
    @user.save
  end
end
```

app/views/admin/index.html.erb : The view I use to create for now  (Currently the source of my problems)

```
          <%= form_for @user, as: resource_name do |f|  %>
              <%= devise_error_messages! %>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :name %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :email %><br />
                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                <% end %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
              </div>

                <div class="field">

                  <%= f.select(:role) do %>
                    <% [['Admin', "admin"], ['User', "user"]].each do |c| -%>
                      <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>

                <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
```

config/routes.rb: Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :admin
  resources :accesses
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
        registrations: 'users/registrations'
      }

  root 'welcome#index'
```

The ERROR: This is my current error:

[image]

If someone has a better way to do it or a link to help me - I'm recently learning Rails so any reading would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method users_path

By default, `form_for` when used with **model instance**(i.e, `@user` here) routes to its corresponding **restful route**(i.e, `users_path` here).

I can see that you are trying to map it to the `admin#create`, so you need to explicitly mention the path to the url in the `form_for` like so

```
<%= form_for @user, as: resource_name, url: admin_index_path do |f|  %>
```

By that, you also need to change your `params` in the `admin#create` as the params will be inside a `user` hash, so for example `params[:name]` should be changed to `params[:user][:name]`

Comment: Thanks for responding but now generate this error:  ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin"} missing required keys: [:id]):

Comment: @J.leo Apologies it should be `admin_index_path`. Updated my answer

Comment: @J.leo Glad to help :)